Error creating apk-file using buildozer (kivy)
- [WARNING]: ERROR: /home/user/PycharmProjects/magic_ball/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64 -v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/magic/gradlew failed!
- No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
- Applying Java source code patches...
- Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
- Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
- Command failed: \['/home/user/PycharmProjects/magic_ball/.venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'apk', '--bootstrap', 'sdl2', '--dist_name', 'magic', '--name', 'Magic_ball', '--version', '0.1', '--package', 'org.test.magic', '--minsdk', '21', '--ndk-api', '21', '--private', '/home/user/PycharmProjects/magic_ball/.buildozer/android/app', '--android-entrypoint', 'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity', '--android-apptheme', '@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar', '--orientation', 'portrait', '--window', '--enable-androidx', '--copy-libs', '--arch', 'arm64-v8a', '--arch', 'armeabi-v7a', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/user/PycharmProjects/magic_ball/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug'\]
- ENVIRONMENT:
- SHELL = '/bin/bash'
- SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/Alonso:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1692,unix/Alonso:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1692'
- QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
- SNAP_REVISION = '404'
- XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
- XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
- GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
- SNAP_REAL_HOME = '/home/user'
- TERMINAL_EMULATOR = 'JetBrains-JediTerm'
- SNAP_USER_COMMON = '/home/user/snap/pycharm-community/common'
- GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
- SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
- MEMORY_PRESSURE_WRITE = 'c29tZSAyMDAwMDAgMjAwMDAwMAA='
- TERM_SESSION_ID = '7673aa59-bce7-47e2-86d8-a6bbb917b874'
- SNAP_INSTANCE_KEY = ''
- XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
- DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
- BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop'
- GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
- SNAP_EUID = '1000'
- PWD = '/home/user/PycharmProjects/magic_ball'
- XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
- LOGNAME = 'user'
- XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'wayland'
- SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '1740'
- XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.63Y1R2'
- DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID = 'gnome-shell/PyCharm Community Edition/1740-1-Alonso_TIME1283125'
- SNAP_CONTEXT = 'dLyFl0eXQe_oiN5ZWr00Gu9SgRwd6R2JY6tcZybQJH2u0zRwRbka'
- GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
- HOME = '/home/user'
- USERNAME = 'user'
- IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
- LANG = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
- LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=00:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.avif=01;35:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:*\~=00;90:*#=00;90:*.bak=00;90:*.crdownload=00;90:*.dpkg-dist=00;90:*.dpkg-new=00;90:*.dpkg-old=00;90:*.dpkg-tmp=00;90:*.old=00;90:*.orig=00;90:*.part=00;90:*.rej=00;90:*.rpmnew=00;90:*.rpmorig=00;90:*.rpmsave=00;90:*.swp=00;90:*.tmp=00;90:*.ucf-dist=00;90:*.ucf-new=00;90:\*.ucf-old=00;90:'
- XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
- VIRTUAL_ENV = '/home/user/PycharmProjects/magic_ball/.venv'
- MEMORY_PRESSURE_WATCH = '/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service/memory.pressure'
- WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
- SNAP_ARCH = 'amd64'
- SNAP_INSTANCE_NAME = 'pycharm-community'
- SNAP_USER_DATA = '/home/user/snap/pycharm-community/404'
- INVOCATION_ID = '527727081bce47d98a679e9db622a5ae'
- MANAGERPID = '1517'
- SNAP_REEXEC = ''
- SNAP_UID = '1000'
- GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
- GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY = ':1'
- XDG_ACTIVATION_TOKEN = 'gnome-shell/PyCharm Community Edition/1740-1-Alonso_TIME1283125'
- LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
- XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
- TERM = 'xterm-256color'
- LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
- USER = 'user'
- SNAP = '/snap/pycharm-community/404'
- SNAP_COMMON = '/var/snap/pycharm-community/common'
- SNAP_VERSION = '2024.1.6'
- DISPLAY = ':0'
- SHLVL = '1'
- SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH = '/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32:/var/lib/snapd/void'
- GSM_SKIP_SSH_AGENT_WORKAROUND = 'true'
- SNAP_COOKIE = 'dLyFl0eXQe_oiN5ZWr00Gu9SgRwd6R2JY6tcZybQJH2u0zRwRbka'
- QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
- VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT = '.venv'
- SNAP_DATA = '/var/snap/pycharm-community/404'
- XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
- PS1 = ('(.venv) \\\[\\e\]0;\\u@\\h: '
- '\\w\\a\\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\\[\\033\[01;32m\\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]:\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]\\$ ')
- DEBUGINFOD_URLS = 'https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com '
- SNAP_NAME = 'pycharm-community'
- JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:12145'
- XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
- PATH = '/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/user/PycharmProjects/magic_ball/.venv/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin'
- GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
- DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
- GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '3055'
- GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop'
- \_ = '/home/user/PycharmProjects/magic_ball/.venv/bin/buildozer'
- PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/user/.buildozer/android/packages'
- ANDROIDSDK = '/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
- ANDROIDNDK = '/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
- ANDROIDAPI = '31'
- ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
- 
- Buildozer failed to execute the last command
- The error might be hidden in the log above this error
- Please read the full log, and search for it before
- raising an issue with buildozer itself.
- In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
